# Does Einstein Article Recommendations consider Data Categories when building its model?

Tags: knowledge, einstein-recommendations

The documentation for building a model for [Einstein Article Recommendations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.einstein_article_recommendations_how.htm&type=5) doesn't mention **Data Categories**.  But it does mention that you may specify custom fields from the **Article** object to be considered in the model.

Does that mean that mean that if **Data Categories** contain information that is relevant to the model, we will need to copy them into custom fields on the **Article** object?

Answer (score 0):

Articles don’t need any special tags, data categories, or metadata to be recommended. You can check this article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.einstein_article_recommendations_prepare.htm&type=5